# What is the right php array for this json output?

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

I want to have this JSON output;

```
                          [
                            {c: [
                                {v: "1"},
                                {v: 90}
                            ]},
                            {c: [
                                {v: "2"},
                                {v: 80}
                            ]}
                          ]
```

This is my php code;

```
            $data = array('c' => ( array('v'=>1 ), array('v'=>90 ) ),
                                 ( array('v'=>2 ), array('v'=>80 ) )
                    );
            echo json_encode($data);
```

The syntax is not even right and I have spent some time adding brackets here and there but the error is still there. How to get the right php array to achieve the desired json output?

Thank you very much.

Comment: And what is the ouput you get now?

Comment: Sad to say, I am stuck at syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should recreate the array like this to get the expected `JSON`.

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    0 =>
        array(
            'c' =>
                array(
                    0 =>
                        array(
                            'v' => '1',
                        ),
                    1 =>
                        array(
                            'v' => 90,
                        ),
                ),
        ),
    1 =>
        array(
            'c' =>
                array(
                    0 =>
                        array(
                            'v' => '2',
                        ),
                    1 =>
                        array(
                            'v' => 80,
                        ),
                ),
        ),
);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
[{"c":[{"v":"1"},{"v":90}]},{"c":[{"v":"2"},{"v":80}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'c' => array(
            array('v' => 1), 
            array('v' => 90,) 
    ),
    'd' => array(
            array('v' => 2), 
            array('v' => 90,) 
    ),
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Output as you wanted, only second 'c' changed to 'd':
    {"c":[{"v":1},{"v":90}],"d":[{"v":2},{"v":90}]}

Answer (score 1):

enclose the array with array to get the `[` notation

```
<?php
$data = array(array('c' => array(array('v'=>1 ),array('v'=>90 )) ,array(array('v'=>2 ,array('v'=>80 )) )));
echo json_encode($data);
```

output:

```
[{"c":[{"v":1},{"v":90}],"0":[{"v":2,"0":{"v":80}}]}]
```